# Single column completion?

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, text-editing

TL;DR: Is it possible to make emacs use single-column completion?

---

When using emacs' completion mechanisms and there are multiple
possibilities, then completions are displayed in a separate window,
e.g.

```
Possible completions are:
i                                  i-search
i1                                 i18n
i2                                 i3
iar                                ibm
ibm1047                            ibm1047-dos
ibm1047-mac                        ibm1047-unix
ibm437                             ibm437-dos
ibm437-mac                         ibm437-unix
ibm775                             ibm775-dos
ibm775-mac                         ibm775-unix
ibm850                             ibm850-dos
ibm850-mac                         ibm850-unix
ibm851                             ibm851-dos
ibm851-mac                         ibm851-unix
ibm852                             ibm852-dos
ibm852-mac                         ibm852-unix
ibm855                             ibm855-dos
ibm855-mac                         ibm855-unix
ibm857                             ibm857-dos
```

While this format is perfectly fine for a few items, when the list is
long having successive completions on the same line, i.e. ordered as

```
1    2
3    4
5    6
```

is rather distracting. Ideally I'd prefer an ordering

```
1    4
2    5
3    6
```

but I fear this is not possible, since it wouldn't be able to handle
completions, that are wider than each column. Emacs in this case uses
a format

```
111  222
33333333
444  5555
```

which works only because of the "horizontal first" ordering; Also my
preferred ordering would require adjustig the completion-buffer
contents depending on window height (likewise unpracticable).

So as an alternative I'd like completion to use only one column, i.e.

```
Possible completions are:
i                                  
i-search
i1                                 
i18n
i2                                 
i3
iar                                
ibm
ibm1047                            
ibm1047-dos
ibm1047-mac                        
ibm1047-unix
ibm437                             
ibm437-dos
ibm437-mac                         
ibm437-unix
```

which I'd find easier to scan visually.

Is this possible?

Comment: There are now an accepted answer in https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/38509/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to change `completions-format`?

It doesn't restrict the output to a single column, tho.
It would be easy to add that functionality to `completion--insert-strings` (which is the function that inserts the completions in that buffer), so maybe you should request that as a new feature.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [**Icicles**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then just customize user option [`icicle-Completions-max-columns`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Completions_Display#icicle-Completions-max-columns) to the value `1`.

If you don't want a single column *always*, you can change the `*Completions*` display [on the fly incrementally](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Completions_Display#ChangeCompletionsSpacingOnTheFly), changing the space between candidates or the number of columns to use.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest to have a look at this: https://github.com/oantolin/live-completions